# Getting 'unordered' semantics in Rust

Tags: rust, atomic

How do I create a fixed length list of integers `V` with the "unordered" semantics of LLVM (see https://llvm.org/docs/Atomics.html).

The "unordered" semantics means if you read a location in the thread, you will get a previously written value (not necessarily the most recent one, as the optimisers is allowed to rearrange / cache values from the array). This can be viewed as the "natural" behaviour of reading and writing the raw memory, as long as values are only written and read in a single CPU instruction (so other threads never see "half a written value").

It is important to me this is as close to the performance of a single-threaded array of integers as possible, because writes are extremely rare, and I am happy for them to be lost.

Comment: Have you benchmarked the overhead of `Relaxed` ordering? (and which platform are you targeting?)

Comment: Mostly x86. I'm coming from a C++ background, where I did find a (small) difference between Relaxed and Unordered. Without being able to try unordered in Rust, I'm not really sure what to compare against? I suppose no locking at all?

Comment: Yes, I would benchmark single-thread performance with relaxed atomics vs raw integrals and check how big the gap is. If it's small enough, maybe it doesn't matter? The use of atomics should disable certain compiler optimizations (two subsequence reads may return different results), but maybe the algorithm can be tweaked to limit access to the array (caching reads in local variables) to recover most of the loss performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rustc exposes a fair number of LLVM intrinsics through the `std::intrinsics` module, which is permanently unstable.

Still, it is available in Nightly, and there you can find:

- [`atomic_load_unordered`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/intrinsics/fn.atomic_load_unordered.html),
- [`atomic_store_unordered`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/intrinsics/fn.atomic_store_unordered.html).

With those at hand, you can use `UnsafeCell` as a basic building block to build your own `UnorderedAtomicXXX`.

You can follow the [`std` atomics](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/sync/atomic.rs.html#966-968) to help with your implementation. The basics should look like:

```
pub struct UnorderedAtomic(UnsafeCell<i32>);

impl UnorderedAtomic {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        UnorderedAtomic(Default::default())
    }

    pub fn load(&self) -> i32 {
        unsafe { atomic_load_unordered(self.0.get()) }
    }

    pub fn store(&self, i: i32) {
        unsafe { atomic_store_unordered(self.0.get(), i) }
    }

    unsafe fn raw(&self) -> *mut i32 { self.0.get() }
}
```

It's unclear whether you can get unordered compare/exchange or fetch/add.